# Redefinition of fields and interpretation of the particle content

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, s-matrix-theory, elementary-particles

Suppose I have some Lagrangian $\mathcal L_1$ involving multiple fields $\phi_i$ with interactions. I can reparametrize the Lagrangian in terms of new fields $\psi_i$ by inserting some parametrizations $\phi_i(\psi_i)$. This would lead to a completely different Lagrangian $\mathcal L_2$ with different kinetic terms, mass terms and interactions. From my understanding there is something called "S-matrix equivalence theorem" which states that S-matrix elements are not changed under this redefinition (given of course some constraints on the allowed redefinitions, but the details are not important to the question). But the interpretation of $\mathcal L_2$ would be completely different from $\mathcal L_1$, especially since the particle states are determined only by the "free" part of the Lagrangian, we would get different particles with different interactions in both cases.

Does this mean the particles we have in the standard model follow from an arbitrary choice of parametrization of the Lagrangian? Could we reformulate the whole thing in terms of different particles with different masses etc? If so why do we use the ones we use?

Comment: Can you get different free parts if you insist on the kinetic terms being diagonal? I suspect the constraints actually are important for this question.

Comment: A couple of comments: (1) these field redefinitions should be thought of as the same as canonical transformations for position and momentum in classical mechanics, (2) while they do not change the S-matrix, the correlations will differ, and (3) this result suggests that one should not really identify fields themselves (which are generally not observable) with particles.